# how to get back to own profile after searching for an invalid username in the URL

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel.I have a controller called `userController` to mangae user in my application.Here i have a user authentication and profile system.It will send the user to its own profile after login.Sometimes user may wish to search for a random username or id field in the url to search for a user.If desired user is found ,their profile info will be shown in the profile section.But if no user is found i want my application to get the current logged in user and show his/her info instead.How i can do that?

if my user name is `'zim'` i can write the url `mydomain/user/zim` ,it will get my profile,But if i search an invalid name say `'zi' mydomain/user/zi` , i want my application to return `mydomain/user/zim again`

***All i can manage here is to show a flash message if no user is found.Can't figure out how to retrieve the current logged user.Tried to use the Request class but seems not working***

**loginUser function():**

```
public function loginUser(Request $request){

    $data = $request->all();

    $rules = array(
       'name' => 'required',
       'password'=>'required'
    );

    // Create a new validator instance.
    $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){

        $errors=$validator->messages();
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator);

    }else{

        if(Auth::attempt(['name'=>$request['name'],'password'=>$request['password']])){

            return redirect()->route('user.show',[$request['name']]);
        }else{
            return redirect()->back()->with('data', 'wrong username or password');
        }
    }
}
```

**show() method in userController:**

```
public function show($user,Request $request) // tried with  Request but failed
{
    //
    $indicator=is_numeric($user)?'id':'name';
    $info=userModel::where($indicator,'=',$user)->get()->first();
    if($info){
       return View::make('user.show')->with('user',$info);
    }else{
       session()->flash('message','no user');
       return View::make('user.show');
    }
}
```

Comment: `Auth::user()` will return the current user. You can grab their username and redirect their in the else where you are showing the flash message.

Comment: how to get the name property form Auth::user() ?

Comment: `Auth::user()->name` or in your case, I assume it should be something like  `Auth::user()->username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your show method slightly.

```
public function show($user,Request $request)
{

    $indicator=is_numeric($user)?'id':'name';
    $info=userModel::where($indicator,'=',$user)->get()->first();

    if(empty($info)){
       return View::make('user.show')->with('user',$info);
   }else{
      session()->flash('message','no user but here is your info :)');
      return View::make('user.show')->with('user', Auth::user());
   }
}
```

Edited for better logic.

Comment: shouldn't i get the name property from Auth::user() ?? currently not fetching anything

Comment: Yes. Sorry I thought you were providing all user to the view. If $user is id then try Auth::user()->id instead or name Auth::user()->name if you are using the name.

Comment: `$info=userModel::where($indicator,'=', Auth::user())->get()->first();` This query is redundant. Auth::user() is already there. Why do you wanna query it again?

Comment: @JilsonThomas I guess I was just trying to show where to logic is but you're right it's redundant and the answer is now edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function show($username)
{

    $info = userModel::where(username, $username)->get()->first();

    if($info != null){
       return View::make('user.show')->with('user', $info);
   }
   else{
      session()->flash('message','No user found! But here is your info!');
      return View::make('user.show')->with('user',Auth::user());
   }
}
```

Here is a much simplified option. (Always allow the URL to collect only one type instead of checking if its `id` or `username`)